# How to resolve error: Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 65536 bytes for committing reserved memory

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm running 3 spring boot microservices, an eureka service and kafka service by docker compose. This is the yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.6.26
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: user
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  flyway-service-i:
    image: service/flyway-service
    volumes:
     - "..\\resources\\db\\migration:/migrations/ro"
    depends_on:
     - mysqldb
    links:
     - mysqldb
    command: migrate -url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/db -user=user-password=password -baselineOnMigrate=true -locations='filesystem:/migrations'

  flyway-service-2:
    image: service/flyway-service
    volumes:
      - "..\\..\\..\\..\\advertisementService\\src\\main\\resources\\db\\migration:/migrations/ro"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    links:
      - mysqldb
    command: migrate -url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/db -user=user -password=password -baselineOnMigrate=true -locations='filesystem:/migrations'

  flyway-service-3:
    image: service/flyway-service
    volumes:
      - "..\\..\\..\\..\\service\\src\\main\\resources\\db\\migration:/migrations/ro"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    links:
      - mysqldb
    command: migrate -url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/db -user=user-password=password -baselineOnMigrate=true -locations='filesystem:/migrations'

  kafka:
    image: spotify/kafka
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      ADVERTISED_HOST: 192.168.99.100
      ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092

  eureka-service:
    image: service/eureka-server
    ports:
    - "8761:8761"

  user-service:
    image: service/user-service
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    links:
     - mysqldb
     - eureka-service
    depends_on:
     - eureka-service
     - kafka
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/db
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=compose

  advertisement-service:
     image: service/advertisement-service
     ports:
     - "8070:8070"
     links:
     - mysqldb
     - eureka-service
     depends_on:
     - eureka-service
     - kafka
     environment:
     - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/db
     - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user
     - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
     - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=compose

  image-service:
    image: service/image-service
    ports:
      - "8060:8060"
    links:
      - mysqldb
      - eureka-service
    depends_on:
      - eureka-service
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/db
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=user
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=compose
```

When the services are starting, the console shows this error:

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 65536 bytes for committing reserved memory.

How can I fix this problem? My computer with Windows 10 has 8GB of memory RAM.

This is the machine in Virtual Box, I realized that in Memory has 1GB, could it be the problem?
[image]

Comment: How much memory do the docker containers need overall? If we assume that Win 10 eats 4GB of memory, then there are 4 GB left for the containers. Knowing Spring, it could be possible that your machine simply does not have enough RAM to run this load.

Comment: Which container produces that error?  Do other paths for running the program produce the same error (`docker run` the image directly, run a native JVM)?  What kind of Docker are you using, and have you configured any particular memory settings for Docker?

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Turing85. About your question "How much memory do the docker containers need overall?" I don't know how to know that :/ is it possible to set JVM_ARGS?

Comment: @DavidMaze the contarner that produce the error are the 3 spring boot services, userService, adService and imageService) This error started when I added kafka to the yml file. I don't have any particular memoty setting for Docker. Thanks!

Comment: Could the Virtual box's machine configuration the problem? It has 1GB as memory @Turing85

Comment: Could be. I am not running docker with virtual box, so I have no first-hand experience with Docker+virtualbox, but if this is the memory for all docker containers combined, this seems too low. Try bumping it up to 3 GB (or how much your system can handle).